# Reading and writing variables with loops

Tags: python

I wanted to code a program thats makes variables with loops like this:

```
for k in range(5):
    exec(f'test_{k} = k')
```

But the problem is that I want to do the same thing but reading the values from the variables:

```
for k in range(5):
    print('test_'+ k )
```

I know that it is not gonna work because:

1. it is int to str (it is giving this error)
2. it is not gonna print the value of the variable (because he dosent know that it is a variable)

Can someone help me?

Comment: use eval in the loop `print(eval(f"test_{k}"))`

Comment: Simply don't do that, this is what [`list`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) are for...

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you already solved it in your first example (`f'test_{k} = k'`), so you would do the same in your second example.

```py
for k in range(5):
    exec(f'print(test_{k})')
```

Or you can read the value first with `exect(f'test_{k}')` or `eval(f'test_{k}')` then do whatever you want with it.

Or even using `globals()` or `locals()`.

Comment: Thank you , But can I do this but in a if?

Comment: Can you share an example of the usage you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `print()` you are using literally prints the strings, and it should cast error because strings and ints cannot be concatenated:

```
for k in range(5):
    print(globals()[f'test_{k}'])
```

Second, `eval()` can be dangerous if input is malicious, so to avoid it use `globals()`:

```
for k in range(5):
    globals()[f'test_{k}'] = k
```

And finally, Best way is to use dictionary for this:

```
varDic = {f'test_{k}':k for k in range(5)}
```

And retrieve like:

```
varDic['test_3']
```

inside a loop or other.